# Xiaomi devices not sending broadcast for the first 5 minutes after boot

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, xiaomi

I have a BroadcastReceiver that receives all kind of actions, some are from within the app to itself(settings) and some are from the device(Charging, Wifi, etc...)

With all other devices my BroadcastReceiver receives the wanted broadcasts but on Xiaomi devices the broadcast won't arrive at all for the first 5 minutes after boot, after 5 minutes the broadcasts arrives as needed

Is there a way to bypass these 5 minutes and receive the broadcast like other devices?

The BroadcastReceiver is registered in the manifest like this

`Manifest`

```
<receiver android:name=".modules.receiver.StateChangedBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                etc...
           </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```